# Using TabPageIndicator with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator, navigation-drawer

When using the TabPageIndicator (from ViewPagerIndicator lib) and a Navigation Drawer together I get the exception "ViewPager not bound".

I've tried with both the SideMenu lib, and the android support lib Nav Drawer implementation and get the same results. The problem lies in that the DrawerLayout calls onMeasure(..) for its children before the ViewPager is set throwing the exception.

Line 114: https://github.com/JakeWharton/AndroidViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/TabPageIndicator.java)

Here's the stacktrace:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager has not been bound.
        at com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.setCurrentItem(TabPageIndicator.java:240)
        at com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.onMeasure(TabPageIndicator.java:116)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the code that you are using?

Comment: I just setup a trivial activity. For support lib the layout contains a DrawerLayout, ViewPager, TabPageIndicator. For SlideMenu lib use only ViewPager and TabPageIndicator. Initialize code in onCreate(..)

Comment: any news on this? was this reported on GitHub of ViewPagerIndicator?